# How would you save complex nested JSON data structure to MongoDB using MongoDB C# client driver?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have a complex nested JSON data structure below saved in a file data.json.
The data structure is reducted but this will apply to all json data structures.
I read and deserialize the json into C# model.
I then write the object/data to MongoDB using MongoDB C# client driver
How would you save this COMPLEX object/data/model to MongoDB?

### Complex nested data structure, data.json file

```
    [
      {
        "property_1": "value_1",
        "property_2": "value_2",
        "property_3": {
          "_some_property_1": 1,
          "_some_property_2": "some_value_2",
          "some_property_3": "some_value_3",
          "some_property_4": "some_value_4"
        },
        "property_4": "value_4",
        "property_5": "value_5",
        "iproperty_6": "Nvalue_6",
        "property_7": "value_7",
        "property_8": "value_8",
        "property_9": "value_9"
      }
    ]
```

### C# ASP.NET Web Api Demo Code

```
    namespace DemoWebApi.Controllers
    {
        public class ValuesController : ApiController
        {
            // GET api/values
            public void Get()
            {
                var models = CreateModels();

                var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/admin");
                var database = client.GetDatabase("TestDB");
                /*
                THIS DOES NOT WORK
                    IMongoCollection<MODEL> collection = database?.GetCollection<MODEL>("TestCollection");            
                    collection.InsertMany(models);
               */
            }

            private static List<Model> CreateModels()
            {
                List<Model> models = new List<Model>();
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("<path/to/data.json>", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(file))
                    {
                        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                        {
                            string json = sr.ReadToEnd();

                            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(json);
                            models.AddRange(data);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return models;
            }
        }
    }
```

### C# Model

```
    namespace DemoWebApi.Models
    {
        public class Model
        {

            [BsonExtraElements, BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments), JsonExtensionData]
            public IDictionary<string, object> _additionalData;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Was there any errors thrown?

Comment: No error is thrown.  The data is not saved in the MongoDB database.

Comment: @Brian Rogers I have added the answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate the effort to clean this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of team mates, this works. Serialize your model to `BsonDocument` and pass the `BsonDocument` to the MongoDB C# driver insert method. This way you can work with your C# POCO object until when you want to persist it to MongoDB then you serialize to `BsonDocument` array or `BsonDocument` and save it. For this complex model `BsonDocument[]` solves my problem

Save a complex json model with this shape and structure, complex than this shape and structure below to MongoDB

```
//Complex json collection/array shape and structure to save as is in MongoDB

    [
      {
        "property_1": "value_1",
        "property_2": "value_2",
        "property_3": {
          "_some_property_1": 1,
          "_some_property_2": "some_value_2",
          "some_property_3": "some_value_3",
          "some_property_4": "some_value_4"
        },
        "property_4": "value_4",
        "property_5": "value_5",
        "iproperty_6": "Nvalue_6",
        "property_7": "value_7",
        "property_8": "value_8",
        "property_9": "value_9"
      }
    ]





// This works - code snippets
 /*Create a collection of C# POCO from for the json.
 // My assumption is you can create C# objects/collections from complex json shape and structure
 //   Serialize to MongoDB BsonDocument and save*/

        var models = new List<Model>{ new Model()}; // Create C# collection from json
        string text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(models);
        var bsonDocument = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument[]>(text);
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/admin");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("TestDB");
        IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = database?.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("TestCollection");
        collection.InsertMany(bsonDocument);
```

Comment: What if you have a Model, but 1 property is going to be an object and you don't know what values it will contain? I only that it will be an object.